# How to change ImageMso dynamically - Outlook 2007

Tags: c#, outlook, icons, outlook-addin

Currently I am developing an outlook add-in using Add-in Express with visual studio 2012. All the codes are written in C#. I use ImageMso property for adding icons for the buttons in the ribbon. I wrote following code for changing the icon of the log in button (in dynamically). But the icon is not changing when I press the button. Please advice me

```
private void adxRibBtnLoginLogoff_OnClick(object sender, IRibbonControl control, bool pressed)
        {
            if (isLogged)
            {
                //LogOff User
                //Some Business Logics
                adxRibBtnLoginLogoff.ImageMso = "ChangeToAcceptInvitation";
            }
            else
            {
                //Login User
                //Some Business Logics
                adxRibBtnLoginLogoff.ImageMso = "ChangeToDeclineInvitation";
            }
        }
```

Thanks for helping,
Kushan Randima.

Comment: What you mean by "is not changing accordingly"?

Comment: I am sorry. It was bit confusing. Now I have edited the question. Thanks for considering my question.

Comment: did you try invalidating your ribbon control after setting the imageMso ?  Ribbon.InvalidateControl("controlName");

Comment: This code was for changing the button icon(set from ImageMso property) according to the click event of the 'adxRibBtnLoginLogoff'. Please see my answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding icons to Outlook using ImageMso property, those icons cannot be changed programmatically.